# Laravel relationship with additional where statement

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, laravel-relations

I know I can define a relationship by

```
Class Users extends Model{
   
   function profile(){
      return $this->hasOne(Profile::Class);
   }
}
```

is there a way like adding extra query to the relationship like other than foreign key and local key that is available to define, I want to only get those records of Profile model that field `active` contains a value of `1`. Profile model has a field named active. Any help, ideas is greatly appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: I think it would better to do it in a scope, but.. did you tryied `return $this->hasOne(Profile::Class)->where('active', 1);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply try

```
return $this->hasOne(Profile::Class)->where('active', 1);
```

but better approach will be using Scope like this.

1. create a folder app/Scopes and add a new file ActiveUserOnly.php
2. place this code there

   ```
   namespace App\Scopes;

   use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
   use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Scope;
   use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

   class ActiveUsersOnly implements Scope {
       /**
        * @inheritdoc
        *
        * @param Builder $builder
        * @param Model $model
        *
        * @return Builder|void
        */
       public function apply( Builder $builder, Model $model ) {
           return $builder->where( 'active', '=', true );
       }
   }
   ```
3. add this code to the top of Profile model.

   ```
    use App\Scopes\ActiveProfilesOnly;
   ```

add this code in your Profile model.

```
    protected static function boot() {
        parent::boot();
        static::addGlobalScope( new ActiveProfilesOnly() );
    }
```

4. then this code will work in your User model.

   ```
    Class Users extends Model{

       function profile(){
          return $this->hasOne(Profile::Class);


        }
    }
   ```